# Can I enter the UK with my non-EU wife?

Tags: visas

I am Polish, living and working in the UK for the last 4 years. I am about to get married next week with my Brazilian fiance in Denmark.
Two months ago we left to the Netherlands from London, she had a half-year tourist visa). But when we came back to London from Holland, they sent her back to Amsterdam. Border officers said her visa is almost finished and they were afraid she would stay longer here with me than what her visa allows.

She was held until the morning there and sent back by first plane in the morning to Amsterdam...
So that's why I am getting married now, to bring her here back with me. Can I come with her here to the UK straight after marriage, with marriage certificates, etc?

Or is the only solution to apply for a visa after we get married?

Comment: You may want to look at the EEA family permit questions on [Expatriates.SE], especially if your wife is planning to stay in the UK,

Answer (score 2):

If the UK accepts that your marriage is not a marriage of convenience, then they should let her in as long as you can get to the border.  Since Brazilians can enter without a visa, she does not need an [EEA family permit](https://www.gov.uk/family-permit).

However, depending on your tolerance for uncertainty and the consequences of a refusal to admit her (which depend on whether you'll be flying to the UK or entering by ferry or Eurostar), you may want to apply for one anyway.  Doing so will allow you to get an official determination that your marriage is genuine in a less stressful context than that of the border crossing.  If the permit is refused, you can appeal or reapply without being sent back.

On the other hand, anecdotes on this site suggest that border officers are more likely to accept freedom-of-movement claims than are visa officers.